# Why isn't my css applying to my html page

Tags: html, css, flask

Here is the contents of my css file `temp.css`:

```
p {
    color: blueviolet;
}
```

This is the content for my html file `login.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

   <head>
      <title>Working</title>  
      <link href="./temp.css" rel="stylesheet" >
   </head>

   <body>
      <p>This is a paragraph</p><br>
      <label for="username">Username</label>
      <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
      <br>
      <label for="password">Password</label><span><span>
      <input type="Password" name="password" id="password">
   </body>


</html>
```

I am very new to HTML and CSS, but I can't understand why the color isn't applying to the paragraph element. `temp.css` is in the same folder as the `login.html`. I am also using `flask` to host a local webserver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Flask application, linking the CSS directly will not work, and you must instead use the `url_for()` function to point to the static CSS file. You can do that using Jinja templating as follows:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
```

Make sure the CSS file is within a directory named `static`.

Your file structure should look like this:

```
-main.py

-templates/
    -index.html

-static/
    -style.css
```